Avoid ping pong bouncing of event triggers
A quite abstract question, (initially) indepent of the implementation:
I have two programs A and B on different systems, that talk to each other via database hooks: On every Create/Update/Delete operation on one side, the other side is informed of the change and perfoms (after some conversion) the similar change on it's side. So, both side are supposed to always have essentially the same data (each in it's own form).
What is a smart / common / best practice way to avoid this loop:
A gets an update -> informs B -> B informs back A of an update -> ...
So, how is usually determined whether the other side was the trigger of this event, and thus should be notified again, or whether the trigger came from "outside" and the other side must be informed?
External triggers can come in on both sides: A or B.
The sender of a hook is in both cases the same: it's the database's event trigger, the original trigger information is lost at that moment.
I came up with the idea to mark the dataset with some flag "A had it already" and make B read that and not send it back to A (and vice versa of course). But then B also must delete that flag (otherwise the next update in B on that record would't get sent to A), which can lead to a race condition: What if a second update comes into B that moment, which A had NOT already, but this flag is not yet deleted? Then B wouldn't inform A of the second update. Or what if the deleting of the flag fails at all for some reason?
I also thought of a centralized flag, which both can access, the first sets it, the second must not inform the first if this flag is set, and must delete it. But same problem, in my opinion very fragile in terms of timing issues... this time time even on both sides, if they both get updates, they compete for the same flag.
Another option that could work, is to slow down that process, and make use of the fact that external events normally come in a much lower order of magnitude of frequency (because triggered only by humans) than a loop would. So, more conrete: If an event on the same record comes again within, let's say 1 second, it must be a loop, so drop it.
Other ideas?

about "A gets an update -> informs B -> B informs back A of an update -> ...": if B is mirroring A after some update, the changes on B should not trigger a call to A.

Maybe I explained it wrongly: A doesn't inform B, A makes changes on B's database by itself. But this leads to the idea: Maybe it should work like You understood: A should inform B on a different channel, not by changing B's database, to make B able to distinguish. I'll think about that further. Thank You!

yes, either that or since A changes B, changes made from A should not trigger B to try to change A recursively.

The way it is now, B can't distinguish whether the change comes from A or from outside, it only sees a change in its database.
